# Vue,js used with Supabase - can't update signIn button after logging in with Oauth

Tags: vue.js, google-oauth, supabase

```
async handleSignInSignOutButtonClick() {
  if (!this.isSignedIn) {
    supabase.auth.signIn({ provider: "google" });
    this.$store.commit("signIn", supabase.auth.session());
    window.location.reload();
    return;
  }

  await this.$store.commit("signOut");
  supabase.auth.signOut();
  window.location.reload();
},
```

The above function is triggered by a sign-in button, which is supposed to become a sign-out button and the icon of the user after logging in.

When The function fires, supabase redirects me to Google OAuth consent screen. However, after logging in and redirecting back to my app, the sign-in button stays there until I manually refresh the page.

What is wrong with my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on that you need to be aware of. For starters you are reloading your page when you don't need to in the `handleSignInSignOutButtonClick()` function.

When the authentication process begins, your app will be redirected to Google OAuth consent screen as you have discovered. Once the authentication is complete, you will be redirected back to your app and the reload occurs automatically.

The second point is that you can make use of the `supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange()` event to help you. My suggestion would be to listen for this event when you create your supabase client so it listens for the duration of your app instance. During that event handling, you can assign the user to the store (or anywhere you want to save the user data) based upon the state change. Your app can be reactive to state changes.

In your supabase client setup code:

```js
const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL // your supabaseUrl
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY // your supabaseKey

const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)

/**
* Set up the authentication state change listener
* 
* @param  {string} event The event indicates what state changed (SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT etc)
* @param  {object} session The session contains the current user session data or null if there is no user
*/
supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      
  const user = session?.user || null;

  // Save your user to your desired location
  $store.commit("user", user);
});
```

Now you have your user data being saved whenever the user logs in and a null being set for the user data when the user logs out. Plus any page refreshes are handled by the change state event listener or any other instance that might change the user state. For example, you could have other login or logout buttons and the single listener would pick them up.

Next is to deal with the actual process of logging in or out. In your component Vue file (from your example):

```js
async handleSignInSignOutButtonClick() {
      
  if ($store.state.user === null) {
    await supabase.auth.signIn(
      { provider: "google" },
      { redirectTo: "where_to_go_on_login" }))
  } else {
    await supabase.auth.signOut()
    $router.push("your_logged_out_page")
  }
}
```

Finally for your button change state to indicate logged in or logged out, you can simply observe the store user state.

```html
<button v-if="user">Sign Out</button>
<button v-else>Sign In</button>
```

This way your button will update whenever the user state changes. The user state changes whenever a user logs in or out, and your code is much more compact and readable.

Once final observation that you may already be doing anyway. I would recommend that you put all of your authentication code into a single file and expose the log in and log out functions for your app use as an export to use in component files. This way everything to do with login and logout is handled in a single location and this code is abstracted away from the component file. If you ever wanted to switch from Supabase you could easily update one or two files and everything else would just keep working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude! A great piece of advice for beginners like me!

Comment: Good to know it helped you out! :-)